# How to consume the inconsistent json structure for the same key using jackson (com.fasterxml.jackson)?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

In the below `JSON` structure, the `fileMetaData` parameter is having different types. `Jackson` is throwing an exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.XXX.XXX.XXX.FILENAME out of START_ARRAY token`.

Example `JSON` payload:

```
[
    {
        "fileName": "file_name_1",
        "fileMetaData": {
          "abcd": "valueabcd",
          "xyz": "valuexyz"
        }
    },
    {
        "fileName": "file_name_2",
        "fileMetaData": [
            {
                "123": "value123",
                "456": "value456"
            },
            {
                "123": "value123-1",
                "456": "value456-1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "fileName": "file_name_3",
        "fileMetaData": {
            "key1": {
                "key11": "val11",
                "key12": "val22"
            },
            "key2": "val2"
        }
    },
    {
        "fileName": "abc.xyz",
        "fileMetaData": null
    }
]
```

How to deserialise it?

Answer (score 3):

Generally `Jackson` converts `JSON Array` to `List` and `JSON Object` to `Map`. We can use general `Object` type in this case and it will be properly set. We just need to check which type we have in given case and properly cast to right `Java` type. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<List<Item>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Item>>() {
        };
        List<Item> items = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, typeReference);

        items.forEach(item -> {
            if (item.isArray()) {
                System.out.println("List => " + item.getFileMetaDataAsList());
            } else if (item.isObject()) {
                System.out.println("Map => " + item.getFileMetaDataAsMap());
            }
        });

    }
}

class Item {

    private String fileName;
    private Object fileMetaData;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public Object getFileMetaData() {
        return fileMetaData;
    }

    public void setFileMetaData(Object fileMetaData) {
        this.fileMetaData = fileMetaData;
    }

    public boolean isObject() {
        return this.fileMetaData instanceof Map;
    }

    public boolean isArray() {
        return this.fileMetaData instanceof List;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getFileMetaDataAsMap() {
        return (Map<String, Object>) this.fileMetaData;
    }

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getFileMetaDataAsList() {
        return (List<Map<String, Object>>) this.fileMetaData;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "fileName='" + fileName + '\'' +
                ", fileMetaData=" + fileMetaData +
                '}';
    }
}
```

which for your `JSON` payload prints:

```
Map => {abcd=valueabcd, xyz=valuexyz}
List => [{123=value123, 456=value456}, {123=value123-1, 456=value456-1}]
Map => {key1={key11=val11, key12=val22}, key2=val2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can de-serialize the data to [JSONNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) . You can use isArray() method to check and then convert it to POJO accordingly.

1. Read the JSON data as JsonNode

```java
        String json = "{ \"f1\" : \"v1\" } ";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
```

2. Check the JSONNode that using isArray()

```java
        if(jsonNode .isArray()){
            //Do below
        }
```

3. Convert the Node to POJO

```java
        // acquire reader for the right type
        ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {
        });
        // use it
        List<String> list = reader.readValue(arrayNode);
```